# python sqlite qmark "consume" parameters

Tags: python, sqlite, where-clause

my python code:

```
datefilter="2022-01-11"
if condition:
  sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE;"
else:
  sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = ?;"
curs.execute(sql,(datefilter,))
```

The error I got when condition is true:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
> current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

Is there a way to "consume" this parameter without using it into the sql query?

I already tried the following but it's not working:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE; -- ?"
```

Comment: you could use a ``params`` variable that you pass as second argument to ``execute`` that is either ``None`` (=no params) or the desired tuple/list/iterable of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any non-null expression that does not evaluate to `0`, which is interpreted as `false` when used as a boolean expression, can be used wherever you want the evaluation to be `true`.

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE '2022-01-11'; -- yes, this is valid in SQLite
```

because `'2022-01-11'` is implicitly converted to a non-zero numeric value (=`2022` which is the starting numeric part of `'2022-01-11'`), so it is interpreted as `true`, making the query equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TRUE;
```

For your case, assuming that the parameter that you pass is a date, so that it will always be converted to `true` when used as described above, you could write the code like this:

```
datefilter="2022-01-11"
if condition:
  sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ?;"
else:
  sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = ?;"
curs.execute(sql,(datefilter,))
```